# Efficient ANDing ORing multiple ids

Tags: sql

Essentially I want to do something like this...

```
select * from table where (id1 = :var1 AND id2 = :var2) OR 
                          (id1 = :var2 AND id2 = :var1)
```

That is, the ids will be unique but the order will not matter.
The pseudo above will work but I understand that using OR will not be as efficient.
Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: Curious about where you saw that `OR` would be inefficient. I like to think that using operators and functions the precise way they were designed to be used, like what you are proposing, is correct.

Comment: It is inefficient only if the query engine fails to use the indexes properly on queries involving ORs, and end up in full table scan, which happens frequently in many RDBMS

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Different products optimize in different ways.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there's a more efficient way to do it : UNION

```
select * from table where id1 = :var1 AND id2 = :var2
UNION ALL
select * from table where id1 = :var2 AND id2 = :var1
```

- **UNION ALL** will keep the duplicates
- **UNION** will remove the duplicates

---

### Edit to clarify

First, your `id1` and `id2` columns should be indexed.

Next, **your original query is not necessary "inefficient"**.  It all depends on how the query engine reacts to the `OR`.

In such situations it happens frequently on most RDBMS that a path using indexes can NOT be found, which results in a full table scan.

So whenever your query involving `AND` and `OR` is too long to execute, you should analyze the explain plan to see if it uses the indexes or not.

On the other hand, a `UNION` query will return exactly the same results, and it's almost guaranteed that the engine will properly use the indexes. Thus coding the UNION form right away, is the best thing to do.

---

On a side note, the Oracle optimizer has a very first step called *Query Transformer*, that might try to change your query to the UNION form before sending it to the *Plan Generator*. But it won't succeed if the query is too complex.

Comment: And don't forget to have an index that includes id1 and id2.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the database.  In general, your version or this equivalent version (if supported by your database) will use indexes:

```
select t.*
from table t
where (t.id1, t.id2) in ((:var1, :var2), (:var2, :var1));
```

This should be treated as a simple lookup in an index on `(id1, id2)` with two values.

Sometimes, it can help to rephrase this using `union all`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.id1 = :var1 and t.id2 = :var2
union all
select t.*
from table t
where t.id1 = :var2 and t.id2 = :var1;
```

However, I would not do that until looking at the execution plan.